# C++ program crashes when attempting to call get() on a future stored in a vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, future

I am currently working on a project that requires me to store a vector of future so I can measure the execution time accurately, however when I call

```
posterTotal += posterDurationFutures[i].get();
```

the program just crashes with no error message. Wrapping the line in a try/catch block also does not work, as it doesn't seem to be throwing an exception.

Here is my code (please bare in mind that this is a work in progress):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <queue>

#include "TCPClient.h"
#include "ThreadPool.h"
#include "RequestGenerator.h"
#include "ResponseVerifier.h"
#include "Storage.h"

#define DEFAULT_PORT 12345

double readRequest(TCPClient client, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs);
double postRequest(TCPClient client, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs);
string sendViaClient(TCPClient client, string request);

unsigned int readRequests = 0;
unsigned int postRequests = 0;

Storage* db = new Storage();
ResponseVerifier* responseVerifier = new ResponseVerifier();
RequestGenerator* requestGenerator = new RequestGenerator();

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Default parameters
    unsigned int posterCount = 5;
    unsigned int readerCount = 0;
    double timeDurationSecs = 10;
    bool throttle = false;
    string serverIp = "127.0.0.1";

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 6) {
        std::cout << "\nUsage (required parameters): server_IP number_of_poster_threads number_of_reader_threads time_duration throttle(0|1)\n\n";
        std::cout << "server_IP - IP of the server\n";
        std::cout << "number_of_poster_threads - number of threads performing POST operations\n";
        std::cout << "number_of_reader_threads - number of threads performing READ operations\n";
        std::cout << "time_duration - duration of test execution in seconds\n";
        std::cout << "throttle(0|1) - 0: do not throttle message speed\n";
        std::cout << "\t\t1: throttle message speed\n\n";

        std::cout << "\nDefault Parameters:\n";
        std::cout << "\tserver_IP - " << serverIp << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tnumber_of_poster_threads - " << posterCount << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tnumber_of_reader_threads - " << readerCount << "\n";
        std::cout << "\ttime_duration - " << timeDurationSecs << "s\n";
        std::cout << "\tthrottle - " << (throttle ? "true" : "false") << "\n\n";

        std::cout << "Enter dev mode using default parameters?\n";
        system("pause");
        
    }
    else
    {
        serverIp = argv[1];
        posterCount = (int)argv[2];
        readerCount = (int)argv[3];
        timeDurationSecs = (int)argv[4];
        throttle = (int)argv[5];
    }



    //std::queue<future<bool>> posterVerificationQueue;
    //std::queue<bool> readerVerificationQueue;

    ThreadPool posterPool(posterCount);
    //ThreadPool readerPool(readerCount);

    //vector<thread> posterThreads;
    //vector<thread> readerThreads;
    vector<future<double>> posterDurationFutures;

    TCPClient client(serverIp, DEFAULT_PORT);
    client.OpenConnection();

    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < posterCount; i++)
    {
        //posterThreads.emplace_back(postRequest, client, i, timeDurationSecs);
        //std::future<double> durationFut = std::async(std::launch::async, postRequest, client, i, timeDurationSecs);
        //posterDurationFutures.push_back(async(launch::async, postRequest, client, i, timeDurationSecs));
        posterDurationFutures.push_back(posterPool.enqueue(postRequest, client, i, timeDurationSecs));
    }

    double posterTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < posterDurationFutures.size(); i++)
    {
        bool valid = posterDurationFutures[i].valid();
        //posterDurationFutures[i].wait();
        posterTotal += posterDurationFutures[i].get();
    }

    cout << posterTotal;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < readerCount; i++)
    {
        //readerThreads.emplace_back();
    }


    client.CloseConnection();

    delete db;
    delete responseVerifier;
    delete requestGenerator;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

inline string sendViaClient(TCPClient client, string request)
{
    return client.send(request);
}

double postRequest(TCPClient client, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs)
{
    int threadPostCount = 0;

    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point endTime;
    chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point startTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    do
    {
        string request = requestGenerator->generateWriteRequest();
        string response = client.send(request);
        bool isValidResponse = db->addPosterValue(request, response);

        endTime = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        postRequests++;
        threadPostCount++;
    } while (chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(endTime - startTime).count() < timeDurationSecs);

    double totalRunTime = (endTime - startTime).count();
    double posterRequestsPerSecond = threadPostCount / totalRunTime;

    std::cout << "Thread: " << threadIndex << endl;
    std::cout << "Average post requests per second: " << posterRequestsPerSecond << endl;
    return totalRunTime;
}

double readRequest(TCPClient client, int threadIndex, double timeDurationSecs)
{
    return 0.0;
}
```

Comment: You are describing symptoms of undefined behavior due to memory corruption that results in an immediate crash. Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean this is where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code, but after the bug occurs the program keeps running for a little bit before it finally crashes here. This is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: I have tried debugging the code and as far as I can see it crashes at that line. All the futures are still "pending" at that point in time, but as @SamVarshavchik says it may be an issue else where in the code.

Comment: What does "crashes" mean? Seg fault? What caused it exactly? The debugger will print that. Can you run the code under sanitizers? gcc,clang support `-fsanitize=thread` or `-fsanitized=address,undefined`, clang also supports `-fsanitize=memory`.

Comment: @J.Whitehead *Wrapping the line in a try/catch block also does not work* -- It won't work because the functions in question are not written to explicitly throw an exception.  The only functions guaranteed to throw an exception are ones where the author(s) have `throw zzz;` in the function's code, where `zzz` is the exception value.

Comment: @J.Whitehead *when attempting to call get() on a future stored in a vector* -- If you used a regular array, or a `std::array`, with a fixed number of `posterCount`, does the error still occur?  If it did, it has nothing to do with `vector`, but something totally unrelated.